# How serve static files with rack-coffee

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, sinatra, rack

I use the gem [rack-coffee](http://rubygems.org/gems/rack-coffee) to compile my coffee-scripts. I want to use jquery.js too. I put them in the same folder, but it does not work. Rack-coffee also compiles the jquery.js and the compiler throws an error. How can I use these two kinds of files in the same folder.

```
use Rack::Coffee,
  :root => File.join(Dir.pwd, 'assets'),
  :urls => '/javascripts'
```

Comment: the new version rack-coffee remove :static options

Answer (score 0):

The rack-coffee [README](https://github.com/mattly/rack-coffee/blob/master/Readme.mkdn) describes one way to do it:

> If you want to serve stock javascript files from the same directory as your coffeescript files, stick a Rack::File in your middleware stack after Rack::Coffee.

Although [Rack::File](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/File.html) does not appear to be a middleware but a standalone Rack app class, so I would instead use [Rack::Static](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Static.html) before your code above:

```
use Rack::Static,
  :root => File.join(Dir.pwd, 'assets'),
  :urls => ["/javascripts"]
use Rack::Coffee,
  :root => File.join(Dir.pwd, 'assets'),
  :urls => '/javascripts'
```

Comment: I think you should put Rack::Static after Rack::Coffee?

Comment: I know the comment in the README said that, but I couldn't understand how that would work and I think the comment is mistaken. In a Rack middleware, the first middleware to receive the request can act on it however it wants, so in this case it seems like Static should first check if the requested `.js` file is available as a "static" file, return it if so, or else continue on to Rack::Coffee to see if an equivalent `.coffee` file is found. So I think the order is correct, no?

Comment: but I write it after Rack::Coffee, it work.otherwise it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I recently [wrote a gem that utilises the CDN's for jQuery](https://github.com/yb66/rack-jquery). If you add that to the middleware stack you won't need to think about it.

```
require 'rack/jquery'

use Rack::Coffee,
  :root => File.join(Dir.pwd, 'assets'),
  :urls => '/javascripts'

use Rack::JQuery # This can go before or after Rack::Coffee, it doesn't matter.

# add this to your layout's head section:
= Rack::JQuery.cdn env
```

and the page will now use Google's jQuery CDN (see http://jquery.com/download/ for more on CDN's) and a fallback script is bundled with the library.